# How can validate inputs inside v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-validator

[image]

I have `this.userGroups`

> [ { "id": 46, "group_id": 38, "url": "1", "url_num": 1, "max_iteration": 2 }, { "id": 45, "group_id": 38, "url": "2", "url_num": 1, "max_iteration": 2 }, { "id": 44, "group_id": 38, "url": "3", "url_num": 1, "max_iteration": 2 }, { "id": 43, "group_id": 38, "url": "4", "url_num": 1, "max_iteration": 2 } ]

```
<v-row v-for="(urlGroup, index) in urlGroups" :key="index">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
        <v-text-field required v-model="urlGroup.url" label="URL" clear-icon="mdi-close-circle" clearable type="text" @click:clear="removeUrl(index)"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

> `required` doesn't seem to work because I can still submit the form without providing any value. I used to do this in a single text field, but now it's dynamic, I have no idea how to do that.

```
url: [(v) => !!v || 'URL is required']
```

**How can I add a validation rule to all of them to be typed URL, and required?**

Answer (score 1):

`v-text-field`'s `rules` property accepts an array of rules, so you could pass one rule to enforce "required", and another to validate the URL input:

```html
<v-text-field :rules="[rules.required, rules.url]">
```

```js
const isValidUrl = value => {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/17773849/6277151
  const urlRegex =
    /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi
  return urlRegex.test(value)
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      rules: {
        required: value => !!value || 'Required',
        url: value => isValidUrl(value) || 'Invalid URL',
      },
      ⋮
    }
  }
}
```

To prevent `v-form` from submitting, you could disable the <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd>-button when the form is invalid, which is reflected in the [form's `value`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#props-value):

```html
<v-form @submit="submit" v-model="formValid">
  ⋮
  <v-btn :disabled="!formValid" type="submit">Submit</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formValid: false,
      ⋮
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      if (!this.formValid) return

      // submit form here
    },
    ⋮
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-validation-rules-v-text-field?file=src/views/Home.vue)